# Only lists and tuples may be used in a list field Validation Error

Tags: django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, mongoengine, listfield

Hi I am implementing test cases for my models.
I am using Mongoengine0.9.0 + Django 1.8

My models.py

```
class Project(Document):
    # commented waiting for org-group to get finalize
    project_name = StringField()
    org_group = ListField(ReferenceField(OrganizationGroup, required=False))
```

My Serializers.py

```
class ProjectSerializer(DocumentSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        depth = 1
```

test.py file

```
def setUp(self):
    # Every test needs access to the request factory.
    self.factory = RequestFactory()
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(
        username='jacob', email='jacob@jacob.com', password='top_secret')



def test_post_put_project(self):
    """
    Ensure we can create new clients in mongo database.
    """
    org_group = str((test_utility.create_organization_group(self)).id)
    url = '/project-management/project/'
    data = {
        "project_name": "googer",
        "org_group": [org_group],
    }
    ##import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    user = User.objects.get(username='jacob')
    view = views.ProjectList.as_view()

    # Make an authenticated request to the view...
    request = factory.post(url, data=data,)
    force_authenticate(request, user=user)
    response = view(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

When I am running test cases I am getting this error

```
(Only lists and tuples may be used in a list field: ['org_group'])
```

The complete Stack Trace is

ValidationError: Got a `ValidationError` when calling `Project.objects.create()`.
This may be because request data satisfies serializer validations but not Mongoengine`s. 
You may need to check consistency between Project and ProjectSerializer.

If that is not the case, please open a ticket regarding this issue on https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/issues

**Original exception was: ValidationError (Project:None) (Only lists and tuples may be used in a list field: ['org_group'])**

Not getting why we cant pass object like this.

Same thing when I am posting as an request to same method It is working for me but test cases it is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tests should be running using `multipart/form-data`, which means that they don't support lists or nested data.

You can [override this with the `format` argument](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#using-the-format-argument), which I'm guessing you probably want to set to `json`. Most likely your front-end is using JSON, or a parser which supports lists, which explains why you are not seeing this.

Comment: Thanks For your help The solution worked I checked the same on server and the problem was solved. Thanks